# Node on Google App Engine, "Syntax error: "(" unexpected". Works fine locally

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I'm trying to run a node.js script on Google App Engine Flexible Environment. It runs fine when I run it locally on my computer, but when App Engine runs, it gets an error at the first opening parenthesis, namely:

```
Updating service [websockets] (this may take several minutes)...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9]
Application startup error:

> TestApp@0.0.1 start /app
> src/Server.js

: not foundjs: 1: src/Server.js:
src/Server.js: 2: src/Server.js: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! TestApp@0.0.1 start: `src/Server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the TestApp@0.0.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

The start of the script begins with a blank line and follows pretty commonly (lines 1-3):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

Here is `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "TestApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Test App",
  "scripts": {
    "start":"src/Server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0",
    "promise-mysql": "^4.1.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10.0.0"
  }
}
```

I've been using this example, https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/hello-world/flexible, from Google, as an example of how to set it up.

Comment: I'm not a node user, but I see a `: not found` apparently overwriting the beginning of the 1st `src/Server.js:` line. If that would come from the `var express = require('express');` line could it make `express` invalid and thus trigger that syntax error in `express();`? Guesswork only.

Comment: hey @JVE999 , check these things: 1- app.yaml file in the same directory with the rest of your source code 2- run your **gcloud app deploy** from that directory. if this doesn't help to solve your issue can you please provide with the structure of your app and your app.yaml file?